# Ajax Successfully Receive Data From Server, But Failed Sending It

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax works fine :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../../../controller/ctrl.test.php",
    success:function(expirytime){
        alert(expirytime);
    }
});
```

but when I need to send data to server and add this lines, then it won't alert the `expirytime` again :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../../../controller/ctrl.test.php",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType:'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(expirytime){
        alert(expirytime);
    }
});
```

please note that `data` is json data. and I have it on above those codes. so, it's not empty. I just wondering why by adding POST mechanism into my first ajax cause `alert(expirytime);` stop working?

what's wrong with my code? thank you

update : for this test purpose, there's nothing in PHP file, but just echo-ing date and time

```
<?php
$date = '2016/04/30 00:00:00';
echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: what does alert output? `[Object][object]`?

Comment: @guradio : the working ajax output this : `2016/04/30 00:00:00`

Comment: maybe because the server refuses to accept post requests or doesn't like json. Add a `error` callback to find out!

Comment: @wero : there's no error in console.

Comment: @RobertHanson what does the alert output in your last block of code?it is running or not?if not then you dont get success on ajax?

Comment: add the error block...  error: function (jqXHR, exception) {alert(jqXHR.responseText);}

Comment: @guradio : if you mean this code `$.ajax({
    url: "../../../controller/ctrl.test.php",
    success:function(expirytime){
        alert(expirytime);
    }
});` then it works just fine. it alerts date and time as I expected and mentioned before

Comment: @RobertHanson i mean this `$.ajax({
    url: "../../../controller/ctrl.test.php",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType:'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(expirytime){
        alert(expirytime);
    }
});` this is the one in question right?what does alert show?is it even showing?

Comment: @guradio : but when I add this lines : `type: 'POST',
    contentType:'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType:'json',
` then, it won't alert anymore.

Comment: $.ajax({
    url: "../../../controller/ctrl.test.php",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType:'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(expirytime){
        alert(expirytime);
    },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
});

Comment: i would assume that you are returning somthing not JSON from the php file. **check network > XHR** for ajax response

Comment: @guradio : just update what my PHP file looks like.

Comment: use `dataType: "text",` should be ok

Comment: @guradio : you're correct. by changing into `dataType:'text'`, it alerts again. but unfortunately, I need to post data in json format to server. that's why I have this line `data: JSON.stringify(data)` and `data` itself is already generated before and works fine. I just need to get the server response, which in this case is date and time.

Comment: it should be ok. when you specify the `dataType:json` the ajax is expecting a JSON type respond from your php and when you return a string it didnt recognize the respont so it didnt when to success but to error that is why it is not showing any alert.while `data: JSON.stringify(data)` here is the data you send to the php which has no effect on `dataType:text,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery expects the response from PHP to be valid JSON. But

```
echo $date;
```

is not returning valid JSON. When jQuery calls `JSON.parse()` on that response it gets an error, so the `success` function is not called.

Change that line to:

```
echo json_encode($date);
```

and it should work. Or change `dataType: 'json'` to `dataType: 'text'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../../../controller/ctrl.test.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { JSON.stringify(data) },
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(expirytime){
        alert(expirytime);
    }
});
```